# Linker errors - additional include directory issues?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I've never added any additional include directories to my projects, so I'm not sure if I'm doing everything right.

I've added my additional include directories in the properties menu - the directories include the header and .cpp files for the projects I'm linking to.

But I'm getting these errors when I try to compile:

```
Error   36  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned int
__cdecl lodepng_decode32_file(unsigned char * *,unsigned int *,unsigned int *,char const *)" (?lodepng_decode32_file@@YAIPAPAEPAI1PBD@Z) referenced in function
"struct rgbaImage __cdecl getRGBA(char const *)"
(?getRGBA@@YA?AUrgbaImage@@PBD@Z)   C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual
Studio 2010\Projects\ovltest\ovltest\main.obj   ovltest
```

I'm getting 4 linker errors besides that one.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the .cpp and .h files explicitly to the project you are trying to build (I assume you are talking about Visual Studio, correct?). Or, in case those files are built into a library, you will have to add that library in Project properties (Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

The `include directories` tells the compiler where to find headers you include. You need to specify directories where libraries are located separately, and (usually) have to specify the libraries themselves (that are in that location) in a third place:

[image]
Include directories

[image]
Library directories

[image]
File names of actual libraries go in 'additional dependencies'.

Answer (score 0):

Adding include directories doesn't mean the code that is contained within will actually get compiled.  So the code is compiling because the declarations for whatever you are using in those directories is there but failing to link because the object code has not been produced.

You need to add projects containing the CPP files in the additional directories (or add the CPP files to existing projects) to your solution.